# Different NSData initWithData alloc behavior under iOS7 and previous

Tags: objective-c

I have the following syntax:

```
UTF16Char buffer[16];
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    buffer[i] = ' ';
}

NSData *data1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: buffer length : sizeof(UTF16Char) * 16 ];
NSData *data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithData: data1];

BOOL sameSrc = data1bytes == data2.bytes;
NSLog ( @"Equals: %d" , sameSrc);
```

In iOS6 *date1 and *date2 indicates two different addresses, but in iOS7 points to the same address. Is this behavior expected and `initWithData` behaves correctly?

Apple Library says:

> A data object initialized with the contents data. The returned object might be different than the original receiver.

so I assume that the data is copied from date1 to initialize date2 object. Is that correct?

Comment: "Might be different" implies they might not be; the docs are telling you that your assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like perfectly valid behaviour. The documentation does say *might* be different. iOS 5 and 6 both meet that definition.

(My guess is that if *data1* or *data2* are mutable then the addresses would differ, otherwise they'll be the same. If the values are immutable what value is there is copying?)

Comment: Yup, If data1 and data2 are mutable then addresses are different.